# Clicking a div changes another div's content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'd like the content inside `<div class="tcw-content">` to change, when another div is clicked, however I have never used Ajax (maybe it doesn't have to be done in Ajax, but I can't think of a JS/CSS way, examples appreciated :) ), would anyone have any examples for me please? For example, the user will click onto `<li id="tab-tab_700964" class="grp"><a>Group A</a></li>` and as soon as the hotspot is clicked, the content inside the above mentioned div will change.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What content should be displayed? And where is the origin?

Comment: Ajax may be the answer for where your content comes from, but for putting stuff in the div, look into the javascript DOM functions. jQuery expands on those functions and gives you handy shortcuts, as well.

Comment: pure JS solution is `document.getElementById("tab-tab_700964").innerHTML="<a>My New Content</a>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tab-tab_700964 a').on('click', function(){
      $('.tcw-content').html('hey');
    }); 
});
</script>

<li id="tab-tab_700964" class="grp"><a>Group A</a></li>
<div class="tcw-content">
    hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It makes this pretty easy. Your example would look like this:

```
$('.grp a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tcw-content').html('new content goes here');
});
```

To explain, `$` is the jQuery object. When you use it as a function with a string, it finds all elements matching that selector, almost exactly the same way CSS selectors work. Then, there are a variety of functions you can call on these matched elements. In this case, we call `click()` and pass it a function that will be run when the link is clicked on. Inside of that function, we find the div using `$('.tcw-content')` and update its contents by using the `html()` function.

jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is quite good. Start playing with it, maybe using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a content slider.

[HTML Content Slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/content-slider/)

[:: Featured Content Slider v2.5](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentslider.htm)

[Examples](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials)

[40 examples](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/40-fresh-jquery-image-and-content-sliders-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

do it with jquery. Include the jquery library, and then add a new javascript file with a document.ready event. Inside the document ready, just add something to listen for when your div is clicked. Read here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

http://api.jquery.com/click/