# Clicking a div changes the contents of another div

Tags: jquery, html

I know this question has been asked here: [Clicking a div changes another div's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368350/clicking-a-div-changes-another-divs-content)

but I am still having problems "Transposing" the concept on my page.

I currently have 2 DIV elements one with an ID of "content" and another DIV called "html"

Basically I want to change the content of DIV "content" - when DIV "html" is clicked. There will also be 3 other divs that I will be adding in the future so I will also need to know how to apply the same thing to other divs.  I know this is a redundant question, but this is my very first venture into JQuery and I want to understand what I'm doing instead of copy and paste and hope to modify when I really don't have a clue.  I don't want to be handed fish when I can learn to fish.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Code would be very helpful.

Comment: Please show your ([sscce](http://sscce.org/)) HTML, and what you'd like to happen (the 'after' HTML). Also, a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be very useful.

Comment: "I know this is a redundant question" Here comes the relevant comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="footer">
        <div id="html">
           HTML DIV
        </div>
       <div id="content">
         <p>Please select a topic below.</p>
       </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){  /// when document is loaded execute this function
    $("#html").click(function(){ //when element with id 'html' is click execute function  
       $("#content").html("NEW Text"); // replace contents of element with id 'content'  
     } );
});
```

> $("#html") is equivaluent to document.getElementById("html") wrapped in JQuery.
>
> $("#html").click(); triggers programmatic click event :)
>
> $("#html").click(function(){alert("here");}); //registers function that need to be executed when element with id 'HTML' clicked
>
> $("#content").html(); //  Returns innerHTML
>
> $("#content").html("NEW");// changes innerHTML

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VWuSw/)**

Comment: @ rahul maindargi Thank you so much.  sorry I was a bit of a blunder I didn't expect my page to get viewed and I got a million windows open.  serves me right doing too many things at once.  that worked.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I just looked your jsfiddle and looks like you have many divs with id content... normally its good practice, to have only one element with one id... if you want to have multiple elements  when you select content.. its good to go with `class` instead of `id`.. and use Jquery selector `$(".className")`

Comment: I don't understand the difference between class and ID just yet.  I know I can give a bunch of elements properties with class on my CSS and anything else i just ID.  is that not good pratice?

Comment: its fine to have ids... but there should not be more than one element with same id. id as name suggest is a `identifier`. which must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

When you want something to happen once you click on a certain div, you will want to register an event handler.
That is what happens in this line:

```
 $('#html').on('click', function(){});
```

The function here is the event handler. Whenever you click on the div with the id `html` the function will be executed.
So within this function you can change the other div's content:

```
 $('#content').html('New text for old div.');
```

If you put this to your function then when you click on html the text of content will be changed.

Comment: my jsfiddle is a little messy.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I think you will want to post your fiddle either to your question body with a fat **EDIT** or post it as a comment beneath that.

Comment: this all works on JSFiddle but not on my page.  been trying to fix it all day.  anyone out there?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt if you think something is not working on your page you should post the sourcecode.Guessing your problem will neither work for you nor anyone else.